# Logical indexing of cell array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to do

```
myCellArray = myCcellArray{indices}
```

where indices is just `0`s and `1`s, with same number of elements as the number of rows in `myCellArray`, but it doesn't work. What should I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis instead of curly braces to do the indexing.

```
>> arr = cell(2,2);
>> arr{1,1} = magic(4);
>> arr{1,2} = 'Hello';
>> arr{2,1} = 42;
>> arr{2,2} = pi;
>> arr

arr = 

    [4x4 double]    'Hello' 
    [        42]    [3.1416]

>> idx = logical(zeros(2,2));
>> idx(1,1) = true;
>> idx(2,2) = true;
>> arr(idx)

ans = 

    [4x4 double]
    [    3.1416]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to slice a cell-array, use parentheses. Example:

```
%# random cellarray of strings, and a logical indices vector
myCcellArray = cellstr(num2str((1:10)','value %02d'));   %'
indices = rand(size(myCcellArray)) > 0.5;

%# slicing
myCellArray = myCcellArray(indices)
```

Answer (score 0):

What amro said is right, you should use parentheses.

But another critical thing is to use booleans not numeric `1` and `0` here.

so if you have numbers

```
I = [0 0 0 1 0 1]
```

you should use

```
myCellArray(I~=0)
```

to index it. Confusingly, a boolean array is displayed as ones and zeros in Matlab, although it is represented quite differently internally.

Comment: Technically, a logical array is represented internally the same as a uint8 array of ones and zeros (one byte per element, set to 0x00 or 0x01). It just has a different datatype flag, so it's _interpreted_ differently. You can verify this by using `mxGetElementSize` and `mxGetData` to examine the two array types in a MEX function.